# Отрицательные значения порядковой и непрерывной переменной в машинном обучении

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Можно ли использовать числа меньше нуля в машинном обучении и scikit learn в частности?

Например, мне нужно для удобства чтения определить значение выигрыша команды (.41) и проигрыша (-.23), или при переводе непрерывной переменной в порядковую (2 и -1 соответственно).

Как такая интерпретация может отразиться на эффективности работы алгоритма?

Comment: Использовать можно, на производительность это не должно повлиять, но может повлиять на качество предсказаний (правда, всё зависит от задачи)